# Problema em páginas com tamanho %

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Estou a criar uma página onde tenho uma pagina que me da problemas ao usar o IE e o Firefox.
A página em questão possui 3 retângulos um ao lado do outro com um pequeno espaço entre elas.

Para o tamanho do retangulo utilizei: `width: 25%`.

Quando diminuo a página parte do retângulo fica de fora da página e só não acontece com o Google Chrome.

Deixo Aqui o código dos 3 retângulos:

CSS

```
 #TituloRec1
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 100px;
        top: 450px;
    }

#Rectangulo1
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 100px;
        top: 500px;
        background: #333;
        height: 203px;
        width: 27%;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        Color: #BEBEBE;
    }

#TituloRec2
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 480px;
        top: 450px;
    }

#Rectangulo2
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 480px;
        top: 500px;
        background: #333;
        height: 203px;
        width: 27%;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        Color: #BEBEBE;
    }

#TituloRec3
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 860px;
        top: 450px;
    }

#Rectangulo3
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 860px;
        top: 500px;
        background: #333;
        height: 203px;
        width: 27%;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        Color: #BEBEBE;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="TituloRec1">
    <h3><b>xxxxxxxxxx :</b></h3>
</div>
<div id="Rectangulo1">  
    <h3>&nbsp;xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:</h3>

    &nbsp;  <a href="documentos/xxxx.pdf" target="_blank"> Visualizar  </a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <a href="\Documentos\teste.pdf" download="teste.pdf">Download</a>
    <br>

    <h3>&nbsp;xxxxxxxx:</h3>

    &nbsp; <a href="documentos/teste.pdf" target="_blank"> Visualizar  </a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Exemplo Final\Documentos\teste.pdf" download="teste.pdf">Download</a>
</div>


<div id="TituloRec2">  
    <h3><b>&nbsp;xxxxxxxxxxxx :</b></h3>
</div>                      
<div id="Rectangulo2">
    <h3>&nbspxxxxxxxxxxx:</h3>

    &nbsp; <a href="documentos/teste.pdf" target="_blank"> Visualizar  </a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="\Documentos\teste.pdf" download="teste.pdf">Download</a>
    <br>

    <h3>xxxxxxxxxxxx:</h3>

    &nbsp; <a href="documentos/teste.pdf" target="_blank"> Visualizar  </a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Exemplo Final\Documentos\teste.pdf" download="teste.pdf">Download</a>
</div>
<div id="TituloRec3">  
    <h3><b>xxxxxxx:</b></h3>
</div>                      
<div id="Rectangulo3">
    <h3>&nbsp;xxxxxxxx:</h3>

    &nbsp; <a href="documentos/teste.pdf" target="_blank"> Visualizar  </a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="\Documentos\teste.pdf" download="teste.pdf">Download</a>
    <br>

    <h3>&nbsp;xxxxxxxxx:</h3>

    &nbsp; <a href="documentos/teste.pdf" target="_blank"> Visualizar  </a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Exemplo Final\Documentos\teste.pdf" download="teste.pdf">Download</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Adicione também o HTML que você está usando. Pode ser que ajude a identificar seu problema.

Comment: Precisa ser mesmo com `position: absolute`? Conhece `float`?

Comment: Não conheço. Vou pesquisar o que faz

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você possui a propriedade `left` com um valor fixo.

Por exemplo, imagine uma página com um elemento com estilos `left: 100px` e `width: 50%`. Se você redimensioná-la até ficar com o tamanho máximo da tela menor que `200px`, seu elemento irá começar a ficar com uma parte fora da tela, até que fique totalmente fora quando o tamanho da tela for menor que `100px`.

A solução é utilizar uma medida relativa para o `left` também, ou então utilizar `@media` queries para retirar o `left` em determinadas resoluções.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ztttyt0h/1/)

Comment: a solução passa por substituir os PX do left por % ?

Comment: @ChrisAdler É uma das soluções, mas caso seu site irá ter compatibilidade com mobile recomendo o uso de `@media` queries.

Comment: Com mobile penso que não. Tenho de estudar essa função pois não a conheço. Mas é estranho funcionar no Google Chrome e nos outros não. Mas pronto irei rectificar essa situação

Comment: @ChrisAdler Já eu acho estranho o fato de 'funcionar' no Google Chrome =). Adicionei um JSFiddle à resposta para ajudar a entender.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/46saykn1/

Comment: Usei o Left com % e funcionou perfeitamente em todos os Browser's